# Image zoom issue in angular nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, mobile-application, angular-nativescript

I am trying image zoom in my angular app with "nativescript-photo-zoom" and nativescript-image-zoom but its throwing "PhotoDraweeView is not a constructor error" can anyone help me?

my code
html:

```
    <PhotoZoom [src]="photoUrl" (finalImageSet)="onFinalImageSet($event)" (failure)="onFailure($event)"  (scaleChanged)="onScaleChanged($event)"></PhotoZoom> 
    </GridLayout>
```

ts:

@Component({
    selector: "ns-details",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./item-detail.component.html",
})
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {

```
public photoUrl="https:// vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/inuyasha/images/b/b5/ Inuyasha.png";

constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.item = this.itemService.getItem(id);
}

onFinalImageSet(event) {
    console.log("onFinalImageSet: ", event);
}

onFailure(event) {
    console.log("onFailure: ", event);
}

onScaleChanged(event) {
    console.log("onScaleChanged: ", event.object.zoomScale);
}
```

}

app.module

import { NativeScriptUIPhotoZoomModule } from "nativescript-photo-zoom/angular";

@NgModule({

```
imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NativeScriptUIPhotoZoomModule
],
```

})

export class AppModule { }

Comment: I suspect your dependencies are not installed properly which is why you must be hitting that error. Try a clean build.

Comment: i will check manoj. thanks

Comment: i installed fresco and implemented now working fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ng-img-magnifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-img-magnifier) npm package.
Here is a working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-img-magnifier).
Very easy to implement and fully customizable.

```
<ng-img-magnifier [thumbImage]='img' [fullImage]='img2'
    [top]='top' [right]='right'
    [lensWidth]='lensewidth' [lensHeight]='lensheight'
    [resultWidth]='resultWidth' [resultHeight]='resultheight'
    [imgWidth]='imgWidth' [imgHeight]='imgheight'>
</ng-img-magnifier>
```